# WIA - determining the page count

Tags: vb6, wia

I am using WIA2.0 on VB6. 
I could do scanning without anyissues..
But, the problem is i could not figure out the number of pages scanned when it's ADF.
I could see something like this in msdn.

WIA_DPS_ENDORSER_STRING  with a token as 
            $PAGE_COUNT$    The number of pages transferred.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630195(v=vs.85).aspx

But, i don't know how to access this in VB6.
Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks.
-Dinakaran.AS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell this count is probably strictly local to the scanner itself when it has an endorser printer.  It may even be a "hardware" counter much like photocopier counters.  It probably can only be reset using a physical key or administrative password at the scanner to unlock and reset it.  Looks as if it is meant for auditing purposes.

> WIA_DPS_ENDORSER_CHARACTERS (ScannerDeviceEndorserCharacters)
>
> Contains all the valid characters that an application can use to
>   create valid endorser strings. *An endorser is a printer installed on a
>   scanner that imprints a text message on every page scanned.* The
>   minidriver should validate the setting of the WIA_DPS_ENDORSER_STRING
>   property against the valid character set in this property. The
>   minidriver creates and maintains this property.
>
> WIA_DPS_ENDORSER_STRING (ScannerDeviceEndorserString)
>
> Contains a string that is to be endorsed (in other words, printed) on
>   each page that the minidriver scans. An application sets this property
>   using the valid character set that is reported in the
>   WIA_DPS_ENDORSER_CHARACTERS property. The minidriver should endorse
>   documents only if a string is set in this property. An empty string
>   means that the endorser functionality is disabled.

Then we have:

> WIA_IPS_PAGES (ScannerPicturePages)
>
> Note: This property is supported only by Windows Vista and later.
>
> Contains the current number of pages to be acquired from an automatic
>   document feeder. The minidriver creates and maintains this property.
>
> Type: VT_I4; Access: Read/Write; Valid values: WIA_PROP_RANGE This is
>   zero through the maximum number of pages that the scanner can scan.
>   The value is ALL_PAGES (= 0) if the scanner can scan continuously.
>
> An application reads this property to determine the document feeder's
>   page capacity. The application also sets this property to the number
>   of pages it is going to scan.

Comment: Thanks for you response.. But, unfortunatly my legacy application runs only on XP.. Vista or later is out of question. I am trying to figureout a way to count the number of pages in the .tif image that was scanned.

Comment: If you check the documentation you'll find that WIA_IPS_PAGES is a replacement for an older property in XP.  But neither of them will provide what you want.  If you have a multipage TIFF loaded the ImageFile object's FrameCount property tells how many pages there are.